# Unmounted cifs still work. Rmdir returns "Device or resource busy"

Tags: networking, mount, samba, cifs

I've mounted a network folder in the Mysql data folder using:

```
mount -v -t cifs //192.168.1.xx/path/to/folder/DATA -o username=xxxxxxx,password=xxxxx,file_mode=0777 /mnt/storageHDD/MySQL/data/netMNT
```

all was fine but I was having problems setting write permissions for mysql so I `umount`-ed it to try other things, but it still works, has network files visible, and all changes affect the network folder.

Running `mount` shows that the `mount` is indeed removed.

Any advice?

### UPDATE

umount-ed again and it seems to have worked this time? don't get why...

Comment: Maybe open files are preventing the unmounting process. I'm not sure if that's the correct behavior. I would expect `mount` will show the network share still mounted. Run `lsof +D /mnt/storageHDD/MySQL/data/netMNT` to list the files open in your mountpoint and then you can try to kill the responsible process.

Comment: thanks @EricCarvalho, yes it was still mounted, unmount-ing worked and I was able to remove the folder.

Is there any way to mount a folder and give write permissions to other users than root? I'm interested in letting mysql export to csv on the remotly shared folder.

Comment: Add `uid=<user-id>,gid=<group-id>` to `mount`'s options.

Comment: @EricCarvalho you should add your comment as answer, seems the question is still getting some traffic, and it might be useful if users see it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe open files are preventing the unmounting process. I'm not sure if that's the correct behavior. I would expect `mount` will show the network share still mounted.

Run `lsof +D /mnt/storageHDD/MySQL/data/netMNT` to list the open files in your mountpoint, then you can try to kill the associated process.